# Import Log file and transform

Tags: list-manipulation

the data in log file is as described

```
{"a":19,"c":12}
{"x":17,"y":15}
```

I am trying to get list of lists

```
{{a,19},{c,12},{x,17},{y,15}}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, your entries are separated by a white space in the log file? You also have a variety of different types of quote marks in your text. Could you copy / paste directly from your log file, or better yet, share the file (e.g. using [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/)?)

Comment: they are just normal quotes. I changed them in the question.

Comment: im sorry I cannot share the file

Comment: The details are important, don't change anything from the original file and paste a section in your question in [code formatted form](https://wolfr.am/v57OLJu4)

Answer (score 1):

```
SetDirectory@$TemporaryDirectory;

file = Export["test.log", "{\"a\":19,\"c\":12}\n{\"x\":17,\"y\":15}", 
   "String"];

Flatten[
 ReplaceAll[
  ImportString[#, "JSON"] & /@ Import[file, "List"]
  , Rule -> List
  ], 1]
(* {{"a", 19}, {"c", 12}, {"x", 17}, {"y", 15}} *)
```

And if you want symbols and not strings

```
MapAt[Symbol, %, {All, 1}]
(* {{a, 19}, {c, 12}, {x, 17}, {y, 15}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using @rhermans example file `"test.log"`:

```
JSONTools`FromJSON @@@ Import["test.log"] /. 
  Rule -> List /.  s_String:> Symbol[s] // Join @@ #&
```

> {{a, 19}, {c, 12}, {x, 17}, {y, 15}}